# fstab mount is read-only

Tags: boot, fstab, read-only

I'm trying to mount a drive as Read/Write, but for some reason it mounts as Read-Only.
This is the fstab line:

```
PARTUUID=b21e66be-01  /mnt/USB_01     ext4    defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail  0  0
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you give write permissions to the mount point?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm a bit new to linux, but I assume you mean /mnt/USB_01?
it has the following permissions:
`drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 May 19  2020 USB_01`

Comment: It is owned by `root`.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how I could have missed that o.0
I did try to sudo chown it but it wouldn't let me (saying it was a Read-Only filesystem), but after a few reboots it suddenly let me and now it's all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your user to have full access to the mount point, run

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/USB_01
```

Comment: I tried that but it told me it was a Read-Only file system, but after a few reboots it somehow fixed itself... Not really sure what exactly happened.